# PostgreSQL: 'operator is not unique' for array even with explicit type cast

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, operators, postgresql-9.2

I've work to do on legacy system using PostgreSQL v9.2.8 I try to run a query:

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['a', 'b']::text[] && ARRAY['a', 'c', 'd']::text[];
```

which end up with an error:

```
ERROR:  operator is not unique: text[] && text[]
LINE 1: select array['a', 'b']::text[] && array['a', 'c', 'd']::text...
                                       ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Differently from many question asked here about similar issue, types are specified and I can't be more explicit here.
I need to mention that extensions: `btree_gin`, `btree_gist` and `intarray` are installed, but I can't spot any duplicated operator for text arrays.

Running:

```sql
SELECT oprname, oprcode,
    l_arg.typname l_arg_type, l_arg.typcategory l_arg_cat,
    r_arg.typname r_arg_type, r_arg.typcategory r_arg_cat
FROM pg_operator o 
JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = o.oprnamespace 
    join pg_type l_arg on l_arg.oid = o.oprleft
    join pg_type r_arg on r_arg.oid = o.oprright
WHERE oprname ilike '%&&%'
```

shows:

```
| oprname | oprcode        | l_arg_type | l_arg_cat | r_arg_type | r_arg_cat |
|---------|----------------|------------|-----------|------------|-----------|
| &&      | poly_overlap   | polygon    | G         | polygon    | G         | 
| &&      | box_overlap    | box        | G         | box        | G         | 
| &&      | tintervalov    | tinterval  | T         | tinterval  | T         | 
| &&      | circle_overlap | circle     | G         | circle     | G         | 
| &&      | arrayoverlap   | anyarray   | P         | anyarray   | P         | 
| &&      | tsquery_and    | tsquery    | U         | tsquery    | U         | 
| &&      | range_overlaps | anyrange   | P         | anyrange   | P         | 
| &&      | _int_overlap   | _int4      | A         | _int4      | A         | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And listing operators families:

```sql
SELECT am.amname AS index_method,
       opf.opfname AS opfamily_name,
       amop.amopopr::regoperator::text AS opfamily_operator
FROM pg_am am, pg_opfamily opf, pg_amop amop
WHERE opf.opfmethod = am.oid AND
      amop.amopfamily = opf.oid
      and amop.amopopr::regoperator::text ilike '%&&%'::text
ORDER BY index_method, opfamily_name, opfamily_operator;
```

shows

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| index_method | opfamily_name    | opfamily_operator       |
|--------------|------------------|-------------------------|
| gin          | array_ops        | &&(anyarray,anyarray)   |
| gin          | gin__int_ops     | &&(integer[],integer[]) |
| gist         | box_ops          | &&(box,box)             |
| gist         | circle_ops       | &&(circle,circle)       |
| gist         | gist__int_ops    | &&(integer[],integer[]) |
| gist         | gist__intbig_ops | &&(integer[],integer[]) |
| gist         | poly_ops         | &&(polygon,polygon)     |
| gist         | range_ops        | &&(anyrange,anyrange)   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Has the issue something to do with some bizarre conflict between `&&(anyarray,anyarray)` and two `&&(integer[],integer[])` operators?

What I ultimately trying to achieve is creating a two column gin index

```sql
CREATE INDEX concurrently public_some_table_index
ON public.some_table
USING gin
(  (array[text_col_01, text_col_02])  COLLATE pg_catalog."default" _text_ops );
```

supposedly used in queries like

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.some_table foo
WHERE
(array[foo.text_col_01, foo.text_col_02]) && array['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']::text[]
```

Index creation ends up fine. Just using `&&` in query fails as described above.

**Update:**

I've checkd on clean installation of Postgresql 9.2.8 after restoration of schema dump (`pg_dump -s`) as [jjanes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721239/jjanes) suggested. The problem still occurs.

Comment: For what it's worth: your code works in Postgres 9.5 (that's the oldest available version on db<>fiddle as of now): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e6394344d50888c5b43657f39b214b74. Any plans to upgrade?

Comment: Yeah, I believe it has something to do with configuration/extensions of this particular server. Ive just run out of ideas to check. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 9.2.24 with just the 3 extensions you mention.  If you dump with `pg_dump -s` and restore to a fresh 9.2 instance, does it reproduce there?

Comment: What is the minor version for the 9.2 instance you are working with?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Minor version is 9.2.8  I'll check this with fresh instance when I can.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to restore schema only dump to fresh installation, error persists. It is possible that this particular cluster which I'm working on has some problem. But I can really tell what it is.
Also since PostgreSQL 9.2 is not supported it's hard to expect abundant feedback to my question.

I'd like to share what I've done to overcome this obstacle of mine.

In the end I've created new function in `public` schema

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION textarray_overlap(text[], text[])
  RETURNS boolean AS
  $BODY$
    SELECT pg_catalog.arrayoverlap($1, $2);
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION textarray_overlap(text[], text[])
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION textarray_overlap(text[], text[]) TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION textarray_overlap(text[], text[]) TO public;
```

The function takes text arrays as arguments and just calls bult-in `pg_catalog.arrayoverlap(annyaray, anyarray)`.
Having that I've created new `&&` operator for text arrays which uses this function.

```sql
CREATE OPERATOR &&(
  PROCEDURE = textarray_overlap,
  LEFTARG = text[],
  RIGHTARG = text[],
  COMMUTATOR = &&,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);
COMMENT ON OPERATOR &&(text[], text[]) IS 'overlap';
```

That solves my problem, because I suppose now server has dedicated operator for checking if text arrays overlap.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY['a', 'b']::text[] && ARRAY['a', 'c', 'd']::text[];
```

Returns `TRUE`.